# about python Eratosthenes' sieve, what if I can do if I'm using list and int is too large

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making Eratosthenes' sieve algorithm and I succeeded for some integers like 31 and 13195. So I was going to find primenumber of 600851475143. But Python said the integer is too large to convert to C ssize_t.

So here is my code.

```
x = 600851475143
i = 2

tmp_result = list(range(2, x+1))
result = []

while tmp_result:
    n = 1
    result.append(tmp_result[0])
    base = tmp_result[0]
    while base*n < x+1:
        product=base*n
        if product in tmp_result:
            tmp_result.remove(product)
            n = n + 1
        else :
            n = n + 1


print(result)
print(tmp_result)
```

I want to know,

In the python is too long list cannot be made?

What is C ssize_t?

`
thx a lot

Comment: "I was going to find primenumber of 600851475143" What does this mean? Are you trying to find prime factors? Also, remember that removing elements from lists can be potentially O(n), so your sieve of Eratosthenes is extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the list's length but that `range()` is implemented in C. You should optimize your algorithm to avoid `range()`.

A huge list will eat a lot of memory. It's possible if you have a lot of (virtual) memory. But you'd better optimize that too.